# After hashing a password in Django, I cannot login as my password is unhashed

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and so I would appreciate any help I can get. I have just created a form that can change the username, email and password. Currently, when I save a new password using that form, it gets hashed and stored which is the desired behaviour. However, when I login, because I use an unhashed password the authenticate() function fails to retrieve a user and I am unable to login.

Note that if I login using the hashed version of the password, it works. But I shouldn't need to use the hashed version of the password for me to be able to login. So is there any way to login without using the hashed version of the password?

```
class UserProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password',)

    def clean_password(self):
        return ""


def change_profile_settings(request):
    settings_changed = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if user_form.is_valid():

            # user.password is hashed

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            settings_changed = True
        else:
            print user_form.errors

    else:
        user_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    return render(request,
            '/profile.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'settings_changed': settings_changed} )


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        # password is not hashed and therefore fails authenticate
        # it cannot retrieve user so it goes to the else block

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:

                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                message="disable"
                return render(request,'/login.html',{"message":message})
        else:
            message="invalid"
            return render(request,'/login.html',{"message":message})
    else:
        message="work"
        return render(request,'/login.html',{"message":message})
```

Comment: password should not be hashed to login

Comment: Yes, but my form saves it as hashed because that is how Django's behaviour is supposed to be. So, is there any way for a user to login?

Comment: authenticate() should do hashing for you

Comment: If I login using the hashed version of the password, it works. I do not know why I cannot login if authenticate() is supposed to do the hashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your profile form is mismatch...

your `UserProfileForm` `clean_password` return '' string. which should not be like this.

and in `change_profile_settings` method `user.set_password(user.password)` parameter should be form password field i.e. `user_form.cleaned_data['password']`

Answer (score 1):

If you’d like to manually authenticate a user by comparing a plain-text password to the hashed password in the database, use the convenience function `check_password()`. It takes two arguments:

1. the plain-text password to check, and
2. the full value of a user’s password field in the database to check against

and returns True if they match, False otherwise.

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/_modules/django/contrib/auth/hashers/#check_password)

Comment: I did see that. But how do I incorporate that into the code? I need to retrieve a user and the only way to do that is through authenticate(). Even if I verify that the passwords match, if I can't get the user (which is done through authetnicate()) then I still can't login.

Comment: Are you sure you are using instance.password for hashing? Because as the UserProfileForm is a model Form, the newly entered password is accessible in instance.password. 

user.password will be the old user password itself.